# How to create one categorical variable from combination of the set of categorical variables in Stata?

Tags: variables, combinations, stata, categorical

In the survey of categorical ordinal variables of technology, I have to score these technology base on their importance (6-1) and then I have to create one numeric variable from a combination of 16 technologies which has numerical value with the labels (12 of them has the same level(1) and 5 variables have a higher level of importance)  these variables are the answer of companies about the importance of the technology, 5 technologies are more important(with score(6,5,4,3,2) and 12 technologies are in the same level(1)? here there is a cross-combinations of q13 and q14 in the Tech data.
Setting aside missings, q13 takes on values of 1-5, and q14 takes on values 1-3. So, there are 15 possible joint values.

could I create a variable from a combination of the other categorical variables?

`gen tecscore= Tq13q145G*6 +Tq13q14Robatics*5+ Tq13q14bigdata*4+ Tq13q14AI*3+ Tq13q14INTOT*2+( Tq13q14cloud+ Tq13q14Blockchain Tq13q14DataStech+ Tq13q14Machinelearning +Tq13q14Predictivedata Tq13q14Datasecurity +Tq13q14Tools +Tq13q14EdgeCompute+ Tq13q14BioNano Tq13q14Augmentedreality+ Tq13q14Quantum)*1`

Then I rank this tech score!

Do I have to create a group then I have to rank them?

`egen tecscore= group( Tq13q145G*6 Tq13q14Robatics*5 Tq13q14bigdata*4 Tq13q14AI*3 Tq13q14INTOT*2 Tq13q14cloud Tq13q14Blockchain Tq13q14DataStech Tq13q14Machinelearning Tq13q14Predictivedata Tq13q14Datasecurity Tq13q14Tools Tq13q14EdgeCompute Tq13q14BioNano Tq13q14Augmentedreality Tq13q14Quantum), missing label`

Comment: Even with edits, I can't work out the precise question. `+( Tq13q14cloud Tq13q14Blockchain Tq13q14DataStech Tq13q14Machinelearning Tq13q14Predictivedata Tq13q14Datasecurity Tq13q14Tools Tq13q14EdgeCompute Tq13q14BioNano Tq13q14Augmentedreality Tq13q14Quantum) ` illegal as  a term in an expression fed to `generate`.

Comment: Please read and act on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This now seems a question about what best to calculate with no programming issue evident.

Comment: @ Nick Cox,  Thanks for your answer; when I use the second one(a variable which I create by egen group) and then rank that variable, the rank is equal to one for all the variables!

Comment: I guess you just created another identifier by accident.

Comment: What do I have to do to correct that?

Comment: Not calculate what isn't needed?

Comment: @ Nick Cox, I write this code to Rank new variable that I created by the above command but the rank is equal to 1 for all variables!     Resid is id, tecscore is new varible which I created                                                                                         **'bysort Respid: egen desire_rank=rank( tecscore), unique'**

Comment: Sorry, but as stated I don't think this is a good question for this site, and given that view I won't make further comments.